# I'm trying to run this code but it is still sending me the error can't not set headers after they are already send to the client here is my code

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.post("/check", async (req, res) => {
    const nom = req.body.nom
    const postnom = req.body.postnom
    const matricule = req.body.matricule
    const numeroBordero = req.body.numero_bordero
    const paymentOrder = req.body.payementOrder

    const etudiant = Etudiant.findOne({ matricule }, function (err, result) {
        if (result == null) {
            req.flash("test", "veuillez entrer des infos correctes") 
            res.redirect("/");
        } else if (result !== null) {
            if (result.isRegistered !== true) {
                Etudiant.updateOne({
                    _id: result._id
                }, {
                    isRegistered: true
                }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("correctly updated");
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }) 
    
    return res.render("profil", {
        etudiant
    });
})
```

Comment: Please consider formatting the code so it can be read. This is almost always a result of doing multiple things with the result, but it's impossible to know what's happening here w/o formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Once you call `redirect`, you cannot call `render`.

Return after your redirect.

```
res.redirect("/");
return
```

Answer (score 0):

What front end framework are you using and what are you trying to accomplish with this endpoint? It seems like the function is checking the value of the request for a record, the running an update if a record was found.

If you want the render on the ui to be conditional on the result of this api call, you need to render separate html accordingly.

I am used to using react or angular, where I simply send a json object to the UI, and let the ui determine which page to navigate to, or which component to conditionally render.

Answer (score 0):

use `return res.redirect("/");` instead

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You want use async/await but only async is present in your code.

Next, use `result === null` instead of `result == null`.
I didn't test your code, but can you run this code ? I think it'll solve your issue.

> This code use promises.

```
router.post("/check", (req, res) => {
  const nom = req.body.nom
  const postnom = req.body.postnom
  const matricule = req.body.matricule
  const numeroBordero = req.body.numero_bordero
  const paymentOrder = req.body.payementOrder

  Etudiant.findOne({ matricule }, function (err, result) {
    if (result === null) {
      req.flash("test", "veuillez entrer des infos correctes") 
      res.redirect("/");
    } else if (result !== null) {
      if (result.isRegistered !== true) {
        Etudiant
          .updateOne(
            {_id: result._id},
            { isRegistered: true}
          )
          .then(() => {
            console.log("correctly updated")
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      }
  })
})
```